# O que é (View view) no Android?

Tags: android

Normalmente encontro esse trecho em algum parâmetro de uma activity.

Por exemplo:

```
public void onClick(View view){
    //código
}
```

Gostaria de saber melhor ao que se refere.

Comment: Esse objeto `view`, é o objeto que sobre a ação de clique. Esse método é invocado quando definimos o atributo [onClick](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:onClick) no XML `android:onClick="onClick"`, por exemplo.

Comment: O primeiro `View`, em maiúsculo, é o identificador do tipo do argumento. Já o segundo `view`, em minúsculo, é o nome do argumento. O nome é arbitrário, então poderia ser feito `public void onClick(View minhaTelinha)`, agora temos um argumento de nome `minhaTelinha` que é do tipo `View`, assinatura de método equivalente a `public void onClick(View view)`